# Inserting to std::list using reverse iterator changes the value of the original reverse iterator

Tags: c++, stdlist, reverse-iterator

Have searched the net a lot, but couldn't find the answer to the issue.

I am inserting a value to an std::list using its reverse_iterator. While the insertion occurs at the appropriate position as expected, what I noticed is that the value of the original reverse_iterator used for insertion changes. Also the value of a completely unrelated reverse_iterator too changes. I have been able to reproduce this in a simple example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    // Creating a list of values 1, 2, 4, 5
    std::list<int> myList;
    myList.push_back(1);
    myList.push_back(2);
    myList.push_back(4);
    myList.push_back(5);

    // Changing it to 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 by inserting 3
    std::list<int>::reverse_iterator revIter = myList.rbegin();
    while(2 != *revIter)
    {
        std::cout << *revIter << "\t";
        ++revIter;
    }

    std::cout << "\n" << "Reverse iterator now points to " << *revIter;
    // Creating a copy of the reverse Iter before inserting.
    std::list<int>::reverse_iterator newRevIter = revIter;
    myList.insert(revIter.base(), 3);

    // Checking the values of revIter and newRevIter 
    std::cout << "\n" << "Reverse Iterator now points to " << *revIter; // UNEXPECTED RESULT HERE
    std::cout << "\n" << "New Reverse Iterator now points to " << *newRevIter; // UNEXPRECTED RESULT HERE

    std::cout << "\n" << "Printing final list:" << "\n";
    for(std::list<int>::iterator iter = myList.begin(); myList.end() != iter; ++iter)
    {
        std::cout << *iter << "\t"; // Results are fine
    }

    return 0;
}
```

RESULT

```
5    4
Reverse iterator now points to 2
Reverse iterator now points to 3
New Reverse iterator now points to 3
Printing final list:
1    2    3    4    5
```

Is this expected behaviour. If so how can reverse iterator be used to insert items to a list (Or is it useless in this regard)?

Comment: Just a note: "copying" the iterator is quite like copying a pointer. (Note that you "dereference" them quite the same way). So it's perfectly normal that `revIter` and `newRevIter` yield the same value when you dereference them.

Comment: Not sure what the standard says, but this, using the return value of insert, should work, `revIter = std::list<int>::reverse_iterator(myList.insert(revIter.base(), 3));`

Comment: @JBL. Yup, I know that. I just wanted to make sure that I didn't make any mistake. That the value pointed by the reverse iterator is indeed changing.

Comment: @john. Thanks, that seems to be working. Can you explain further on why it works?

Comment: @john_zac David's answer below explains how reverse iterators are implemented. list::insert returns the newly inserted node, by creating a reverse iterator from that you actually get a reverse iterator that refers to the node before the newly inserted node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would avoid using reverse iterators (in general, and in particular for anything other than a sequential transversal). Forward and reverse iterators work differently, in the case of a forward iterator into a list, the iterator tracks the node that you access through `operator*`, but in the reverse case the iterator tracks the next element in the list. The act of dereferencing a reverse iterator obtains the predecessor of the node referred by the iterator and extracts the value from that. Graphically (f is a forward iterator, r is a reverse iterator)

```
  f
1 2 4
    r
```

Both the forward iterator f and the reverse iterator r will yield 2 when dereferenced, but the node they track is different. When you insert using r you insert between 2 and 4, but the underlying iterator is left pointing to the node holding the 4:

```
  f
1 2 3 4
      r
```

Now if you dereference r, the same process as above applies. The predecessor of the current node is obtained, and the value printed, except that now the predecessor of 4 is 3 and that is what you get.

> Is this expected behaviour. If so how can reverse iterator be used to insert items to a list (Or is it useless in this regard)?

Yes, this is expected behavior. How can a reverse iterator be used to insert items to a list? Understanding how it works.

Comment: +1 Thanks, It makes sense now. I didn't analyse it as deeply as that initially. It also explains john's comment.

Answer (score 0):

The invariant after insertion is the `std::reverse_iterator<>::base()`, not the `std::reverse_iterator<>` itself. But, `base()` does target the previous elements compared to `reverse_iterator`:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator

What's bother me a bit is that when I had `std::distance` to the `begin()` (or `rend().base()` ):

```
  std::cout << "\n" 
        << "Reverse Iterator now points to " 
        << *revIter << "-" << *(revIter.base())<< "-" 
        << std::distance(revIter.base(), myList.rend().base());
```

I have:

> Reverse iterator now points to 2-4-3
>
> Reverse Iterator now points to 3-4-3

Or I expect the second one to be "3-4-4" as the element is inserted prior to the `base()`...